# Storing contents of file in ArrayList of Integer using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, large-files

I want to store the contents of a textfile of the following format:

First line contains 2 integers, say n and k,separated by a white space.

The following lines contain n integers (n can be very large) (which I would like to store in an ArrayList)

What I got to understand by searching online about ways of handling files in Java is that BufferedReader is the preferred way when dealing with big input as it is faster(compared with Scanner) and also how to do it. My attempt is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("./interview1.txt"))) {
            t.append(br.readLine());
            String[] firstLine = new String[2];
            firstLine = t.toString().split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[0]);
           // System.out.println(n);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(firstLine[1]);
           // System.out.println(k);
            String line;
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] thisLine = line.split(" ");
                for(int i = 0; i < thisLine.length; i++){
                   // System.out.print(thisLine[i] + " ");
                   list.add(Integer.valueOf(thisLine[i]));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
```

Since I know that the first line contains only 2 numbers, I read the line, convert it into an String array of size 2 and then separate the 2 Integers. All good up until now.

The problem comes next, after entering the while loop. I keep on receiving a java.lang.NumberFormatException (which, as far as I know, means that I tried to convert a String that does not contain a parseable int into an Integer) when trying to add the contents into the list.

Uncommenting the first line in the for loop results in the following output:

```
3 4 2 1 6 7 1 2 2 3 (extra random 2 towards the end??)
```

Content of the file currently used:

```
10 5
3 4 2 1 6 7 1 2 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a different pattern for splitting (**`"\\s+"`**) instead of just a whitespace.

Comment: Just tried it, I still get the NumberFormatException

Comment: @Rosi98, also try trimming your string for removal of any unnecessary characters.

Comment: @praxnet I still get the same after adding a .trim() to thisLine[i]

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @MauricePerry you're right, it is unnecessary. I could have used an array of Strings from the first time (As I did in the loop) instead of using a StringBuilder and convert it afterwards. Thanks! I still get the exception, though

Comment: You have an `n` value of 10, but only 9 numbers on the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be able to use `java.nio`, so I recommend using as many of its features as possible and getting rid of a `BufferedReader`:

My example file *numbers.txt* looks like this:

```
1 2 14 55 165
2
3 4  5  6    7
4

6
7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

You can read it and store the numbers in separate `List<Integer>` for each line in a `List<List<Integer>>` or just store all the numbers you read in that file in a single `List<Integer>`. Check the following code and its comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide the path to the file
    Path pathToFile = Paths.get("Y:\\our\\path\\to\\numbers.txt");
    // provide a list of lists of numbers
    List<List<Integer>> numbersInLines = new ArrayList<>();
    // or provide a single list of integers
    List<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    // try reading the file, you may want to check if it exists and is valid before
    try {
        Files.lines(pathToFile).forEach(line -> {
            // provide a list for the numbers of each line
            List<Integer> realNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
            // split the line by an arbitrary amount of whitespaces
            String[] lineElements = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            // convert them to integers and store them in the list of integers
            for (String lineElement : lineElements) {
                // check if there is an empty String
                if (!"".equals(lineElement)) {
                    // add it to the list of the current line
                    realNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(lineElement));
                    // and / or add it to the list of all numbers
                    allNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(lineElement));
                }
            }
            // store the list of numbers of the current line in the list of lists
            numbersInLines.add(realNumbers);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // print each line list
    numbersInLines.forEach(lineNumbers -> {
        lineNumbers.forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
    });

    // and / or print all the numbers in a single line, separated by a whitespace
    allNumbers.forEach(number -> System.out.print(number + " "));
}
```

The output will be this:

```
121455165
2
34567
4

6
7891011121314151617
1 2 14 55 165 2 3 4 5 6 7 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```